# How to get local function to read other separate local function?

Tags: javascript

If you have two local functions.

```
function a() {
  alert("a");
}

function c() {
  alert("c");
}

a();
```

and in each local function, lied another local function.

```
function a() {
  alert("a");
  b();

  function b() {
    alert("b");
    c();
    d();
  }

}

function c() {
  alert("c");

  function d() {
    alert("d");
  }
}

a();
```

From what I understand, both functions a and c are "global" as they are first to show up in javascript. local function b is linked to global a and local d to global c, so local function b can read global function c, but are not able to see local function d as that are not global function but local function inside that global function, so it can no longer see and call local function d.

How do you ensure that function of d() can be read by the function of b();
I apologized if this has already been asked, I can't think of the correct keyword to ask, and try to search for the correct keyword does not quite answer my question. I believe the answer has to do with the return, but I never got that to work much less so use it for the function itself.

https://jsfiddle.net/Necrorifter/x1L90pvh/

Unless I am understanding or reading this wrong?

Comment: You cannot.  `b` and `d` do not share a scope.  To access `b` from `d`, you would have to access it off of an instance of `a`

Comment: Hey @Necrorifter, if you want to have an accessible structure you can take a look at Object Oriented Programming (OOP) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Object_prototypes

functions are meant for returning a result.
Of course you can return function d as a result of function c and can access it via a variable

Comment: scope isn't a coincidence, it's on purpose.. there r several ways for those things to access each other, but if `d` and `b` can access each other, in the 2 ways im about to demonstrate, so can some random other code

Comment: the quickest way(way 3 cuz im too bored to code up an answer) is to have c pass a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to have each function return the internal functions. Then call them later on.

```js
function a() {
  console.log("a");
  b();

  function b() {
    console.log("b");
    _c = c();
    _c.d();
  }
  
    return {b:b}
}

function c() {
  console.log("c");

  function d() {
    console.log("d");
  }
  
  return {d:d}
}

a();
```

Comment: This one seems useful and simple enough that I can use without rewriting the majority of my code, but it seems that in the end, I will need to attach a function to a variable to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//i made ur code smaller cuz seeing it spaced out spaces out my mind
function a() {
  alert("a");
  function b() {
    alert("b");
    c();c(1)();//when the parameter is 1, the function d is returned, then i called the returned function(thus i called d)
  }b();
}

function c(dd) {
  function d() {
    alert("d");
  }
  if(dd==1){return(d);}
  alert("c");
}
a();
//there is no built in help for something like this so yea i pulled a workaround
```